# States in the tensorflow static rnn

Tags: tensorflow, recurrent-neural-network

I'm trying to work with RNN using Tensorflow. I use the following function from this [repos](https://github.com/aymericdamien/TensorFlow-Examples/blob/master/examples/3_NeuralNetworks/recurrent_network.py):

```
def RNN(x, weights, biases):

    # Prepare data shape to match `rnn` function requirements
    # Current data input shape: (batch_size, timesteps, n_input)
    # Required shape: 'timesteps' tensors list of shape (batch_size, n_input)

    # Unstack to get a list of 'timesteps' tensors of shape (batch_size, n_input)
    x = tf.unstack(x, timesteps, 1)

    # Define a lstm cell with tensorflow
    lstm_cell = rnn.BasicLSTMCell(num_hidden, forget_bias=1.0)

    # Get lstm cell output
    outputs, states = rnn.static_rnn(lstm_cell, x, dtype=tf.float32)

    # Linear activation, using rnn inner loop last output
return tf.matmul(outputs[-1], weights['out']) + biases['out']
```

I understand that `outputs` is a list containing intermediate outputs in the unrolled neural network. I can verify that `len(outputs)` equals `timesteps`. However, I wonder why `len(states)` equals `2`. I think I should contain only the final state of the network.
Could you please help explain?
Thanks.

Comment: Likely because it is a tuple of `(c,h)`: `cell_state`, `hidden_state`

Comment: Do you mean the hidden state and cell state as mentioned here: http://colah.github.io/posts/2015-08-Understanding-LSTMs/. If it's the case, the `outputs` and the hidden states are the same, aren't they? Also, the `hidden_state` in `states` is the final output, isn't it?

Comment: Yes -- I believe `outputs` and hidden states should be the same, unless there is some sort of other "output layer" operation performed on the hidden state.

Answer (score 1):

To confirm the discussion in the comments: when constructing a static RNN using `BasicLSTMCell`,  `state` is a two-tuple of `(c, h)`, where `c` is the final cell state and `h` is the final hidden state. The final cell hidden state is in fact equal to the final output in `outputs`. You can corroborate this by reading the [source code](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r1.6/tensorflow/python/ops/rnn_cell_impl.py) (see `BasicLSTMCell`'s `call` method).